# How to load history from saved model(.h5) file?

Tags: keras

I have trained my model and saved it. For plotting results against that model I loaded the model and now I want to extract history from that model.

saved model

```py
model = load_model('model_pre_ep3_valloss0.360.h5')
```

How do I extract accuracy, loss etc plot from there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That information is not saved a Keras HDF5 model file, so if you did not save it in another file, it is effectively lost.

One simple way to save the loss/accuracy history is to use the `CSVLogger` callback, more information in the keras [docs](https://keras.io/callbacks/#csvlogger).